# Validate input format of textarea in asp.net mvc with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The textarea should allow the input only in the below format. I need to get description from the user in below format using textarea.

```html
<Fix>
  <li>Issue is fixed</li>
  <li>Issue is fixed</li>
</Fix>

<Feature>
  <li>New feature added</li>
  <li>New feature added</li>
</Feature>
```

Either one among fix and feature or both can be allowed as input. How to validate this format? We can validate use string functions. Is there any efficient way?

Comment: Why not using Select-option or Check-box/radiobutton list instead of text area?

Comment: @AnupSharma yes. I agreed with you. If you want to bound user, then it should be some checkbox or dropdown

Comment: I need to get fix and feature details. How radio button / check box will help? My question is how to validate the input format